# How to use an instance of a class in its own class

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 4.x I have a Customer Eloqeunt Model that has a relationship to a Customer_tel Eloquent Model:

```
class Customer extends Eloquent 
{

    public function tel()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Customer_tel');
    }
}
```

The Customer_tel table has a boolean column 'main'.

When I make an instance of the Customer Class in a view, then I can filter out the main number with the `filter()` method:

```
$Customer = Customer::find(1);

$Customer->tel->filter(function($tel)
    {
        if ($tel->main == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    })->shift()->tel
```

But when I try to make a function in the class with the `filter()` method:

```
    public function mainTel() 
    {
        return $this->tel()->filter(function($tel)
        {
            if ($tel->main == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        })->shift()->tel;
    }
```

When I try to reference it in the view `$Customer->mainTel`, then it gives me an error `"Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::filter()"`.

Why can't I filter the instance only outside of the class but not in the class? And is there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the method (`tel()`) returns the `HasMany` instance, upon which you can then call the query builder methods. Using Eloquent's magic properties, you can short-circuit it. So `$customer->tel` is equivalent to `$customer->tel()->get()`, which returns a collection. That is why it's working for you in your first example.

See [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many) for more info.

---

A better option would be to do it in the query itself:

```
return $this->tel()->where('main', true)->pluck('tel');
```

---

Also note that [you can create your own magic properties](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) in Eloquent:

```
class Customer extends Eloquent {

    public function tel()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Customer_tel');
    }

    public function getMainTelAttribute()
    {
        return $this->tel()->where('main', true)->pluck('tel');
    }
}
```

Now when you have a `$customer` model, you can call your magic method directly:

```
$tel = $customer::find(1)->main_tel;
```